# How to check the data received event in serial port C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to read/write some data using serial port,

```
byte[] txTestData = new byte[] { 0x03, 0x0, 0x01, 0x0};
Serial.Write(txTestData, 0, txTestData.Length);
```

But I want to read the data only when i receive data from serial port. ,i.e

```
if(Data received from serial port)
{
   byte[] rxTestResponse = new byte[2];
   Serial.Read(rxTestResponse, 0, 2);
}
```

Is there any API that tells me the data received event ??

Thanks,
Dattatarya

Comment: You can use DataReceived event, this event will be raised when some data is received on serial port.

Comment: @Datta is my answer helpful? Do you need any help?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is an API which can tell you when data is received, it's called events. Read more about events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/awbftdfh.aspx).

Attach event:

```
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

Create handler

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
     byte[] rxTestResponse = new byte[2];
     Serial.Read(rxTestResponse, 0, 2);
}
```

Every time SerialPort receives data it will call [`DataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event and your event handler will execute

Comment: The problem is that in the delegate which would be called by the event you need to check again is a data really came. Are here a way to do it?

Comment: @Hi-Angel this event will be raised only when data is received by client.

Comment: I know. Suppose this event calls the function that gets lock, and sets some variable «PortHasData» to true. Some time later in a «ReadMyData()» I am set lock, next reading a data and set the «PortHasData» to `false`. Achtung: just in the gap between the moment the «ReadMyData()» took the lock and the moment for it read the data, the `DataReceived` could be triggered, and the delegate would be locked. After it released it sets the «PortHasData» to true — but the port have no a data anymore! So in the delegate function I need to check again that the port actually have a data.